# Handle error inside ngSubmit of template form (thrown by synchronous non-http service)

Tags: angular

I'm starting with Angular and trying to KISS as much as possible. I have a form in a template whose `(ngSubmit)` component method calls an injected Service method that calls a synchronous back-end (not using HTTP, everything happens in memory in a domain layer) which can throw exceptions.

For example, if trying to start a game with a player's name that already exists, the domain layer will tell me with an `AlreadyExistsError` on the method to start a new game.

The exception is caught just fine with try/catch as so:

```js
onSubmit() {
    try {
      this.myService.methodCallingSyncBackEnd(this.model.name); // player name from form
      this.submitted = true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      if (error instanceof AlreadyExistsError)
        this.errorMsg = error.message;  // player already exists
      else
        this.errorMsg = 'Unknown error.';
    }
  }
```

The catch is working. However, the front-end seems to hang (the Submit button looks like it's not had a button-up - see the **bold** outline -- **Edit**: this appears to be a bug in Chrome, as the latest Firefox doesn't have the bold outline). I also don't see the `{{errorMsg}}` in the HTML template, which is a bigger problem.

> [image]

The console log for error shows:

```
Error: Player 'Marie Antoinette' already exists.
    at Game.startGame (Game.ts:28)
    at MyService.methodCallingSyncBackEnd (my-service.service.ts:20)
    at PlayComponent.onSubmit (play.component.ts:27)
    at PlayComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_4_listener (play.component.html:5)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:14949)
    at Object.wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault [as next] (core.mjs:14987)
    at Object.next (Subscriber.js:110)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (Subscriber.js:60)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31)
    at Subject.js:31
```

- `Game.ts` is the domain class that detects the error and throws the exception with a message. It's all in memory (nothing asynchronous).
- `my-service.service.ts` is an Angular service injected into the `PlayComponent` that has the form template defined in its `.html`.

This looks like I need some kind of framework-friendly way to handle errors <del>with</del>from a call to an injected service, but I don't want to complicate my code with Observables/Observers if I don't have to, because (so far) I don't need to have much reactivity in my application.

Since there's no web back-end, and try/catch is such straightforward code (easier to understand), I would like to keep it simple. Is there something I can do to "unwind" properly the framework from the catch, or am I stuck using some more complicated code because of `ngForm`/`ngSubmit`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use catchError of rxjs

```
this.myService.methodCallingSyncBackEnd(this.model.name).pipe(catchError((error) => {
if (error instanceof AlreadyExistsError) {
 this.errorMsg = error.message;
}
}),
);
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch

Comment: `pipe` works on an Observable, if I understand correctly. This solution requires that I make all the Domain class methods return Observables? That is a lot of boilerplate just to be able to catch errors in classes that all work with synchronous calls. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to "complicate your code", this solution seems to be not bad. But if you want a "framework-friendly" solution, Angular essentially works with Observables/Observers.

The main advantage to use Observables/Observers is to respect a full asynchronous workflow in all your Angular components. If later a service method will required such delay (API call, processing...), everything will be clean for you.

On your service side, you can easily implement an Observable like this:

```js
methodCallingBackend(name: string): Observable<void> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    // ... your code here ...

    // If an error occurred:
    throw new AlreadyExistsError();

    // If everything worked well:
    observer.next();
  });
}
```

On your component side, you can easily debounce input to provide user an immediate feedback:

```js
this.form.get('name')?.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(400), distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe((name) => {
    this.myService.methodCallingBackend(name)
      .pipe(take(1), catchError((error) => {
        //    ^  take(1): Unsubscribe automatically after response

        if (error instanceof AlreadyExistsError) {
          this.errorMsg = error.message;
        }
      }))
      .subscribe(() => {
        // Everything worked well
      });
  });
```

Like this, your service method will be triggered after each pause of 400ms in user input.

Comment: The debounce idea is cool, but I'm looking for a general solution after a submit. One of the problems with your answer is that the AlreadyExistsError happens when you try to add a player. If I call that method and the name is good, I've added a player! I finally got it to work with only adding Observable to the Service, but the code in the component is super anti-KISS: pipe shows 11 overrides in my IDE, the subscribe you proposed seems to be deprecated, catchError must return an observable, etc. It seems too complicated for handling an exception (at least in the latest TS and Angular).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that only uses `rxjs::Observable` in the Service and a `subscribe()` in the component. The `error` thrown by the Domain class (Model.Game) propagates to the component, which is nice. **Note:** This answer is more concrete (e.g. `GameService`) than my question (e.g. `MyService`).

**GameService.startGame(...)**

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
//...
  public startGame(name: string): Observable<void> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        this.game.startGame(name);  // can throw AlreadyExistsError
        observer.next();
    })
  }
```

**PlayComponent.onSubmit()**

```js
  onSubmit() {
    this.errorMsgGUI = '';
    this.submitted = true;
    this.gameService.startGame(this.model.name) // Player object bound to form
      .subscribe({
        error: (error) => {
          // if (error instanceof AlreadyExistsError) 
          this.errorMsgGUI = error.message;
          console.log(`startGame failed: ${error.message}`);
        },
        next: () => {
          console.log("startGame success!");
          // this.pageState = PageState.Playing;
        },
      })
  }
```

Here's an annotated class diagram (generated initially with [tplant](https://github.com/bafolts/tplant) and modified manually to show packages and annotations):
[image: error-handling-design]